# How to get an area of interest image given latitude and longitude arcGIS?

Tags: gis, esri, esri-maps, esri-arc-engine, esri-javascript-api

I would like to know if it's possible to give a latitude and longitude (or bounding box)for a certain location return back an area of interest image, including a target property and a list of nearby schools in arcGIS?
Me and my manager went through the Esri docs but couldn't find a way of doing it. If not, any suggestion for a different api to do that?

I would like to get something like this image below where the red point of interest is a property and the black ones are nearby schools:
[image]

p.s: I'm using the esri rest api.

cheers for the help!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/309458/115

Comment: Yes, all mapping api can do such things. However, for using ArcGIS api you should have you data (the schools location) stored on ArcGIS Online or on an ArcGIS Server through a MapService or a FeatureService? Is it the case?

Comment: Yeah, was able to do it using the esri printing service, it's definitely something NOT straight forward as I thought it would be, but we managed to solve the situation. I updated my post. Cheers for the msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody helped me and somebody may have the same situation as me. I was able to solve the problem using the ExportWebMap from esri, basically accessing the their printing service. In case somebody needs it, here's the specification.
https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/exportwebmap-specification.htm